# Инициализация типа byte двоичным представлением

Tags: c#

Есть функция, которая записывает байты в контроллер и принимает `byte[]`.
Как инициализировать массив байтов двоичными данными, чтобы было видно где `0` и где `1`?

Использую C# .NET 3.5, Snap7.

Comment: что значит _инициализировать массив байт двоичными данными, чтобы было видно где 0 где 1._? Какими данными? где видно?

Comment: Ты байты с битами не путаешь?

Comment: в контроллере simatic s7-300 данные хранятся в виде байт, мне нужно изменить например 3 бит первого байта и всё,  как мне инициализировать переменную.

Comment: пусть будут биты )... примерчик дайте

Comment: byte []bb=new byte[500]; bb[0]=00100000; вот чтото подобное хочу

Answer (score 2):

В C# 7.0 значение можно задать так:

```
int value = 0b01101101;
```

При использовании более старой версии можно воспользоваться близким к бинарному представлению в шестнадцатеричном виде:

```
int value = 0x6D;
```

Также можно пожертвовать производительностью в пользу наглядности:

```
int value = Convert.ToInt32("01101101", 2);
```

Можно ещё создать константу на каждый бит и использовать побитовое ИЛИ:

```
public const int
        b1 = 1,
        b2 = 2,
        b3 = 4,
        b4 = 8,
        b5 = 16,
        b6 = 32,
        b7 = 64,
        b8 = 128; 

int value = b7 | b6 | b4 | b3 | b1;
```

Но наглядность такого подхода под большим вопросом. Ещё можно создать 256 констант (`b0`, `b1`, `b10` и т.д.) на все варианты при большом желании заморочиться на этом.

Comment: Что значит "планируется"? c# 7 уже вышел и там это есть

Comment: @vitidev это значит, что я был абсолютно не в курсе, что он уже вышел. Ответ исправил.